# Blink browser engine example with Cmake?

Tags: c++, blink

I've been trying to build the Blink browser engine without any luck. Does anyone know how to create a simple window in Linux that opens an URL or renders an HTML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest having a look at [CEF library](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef) which enables just that - rendering content in window using, as a part of it, the Blink engine.

When it comes to running the engine itself it's tricky - mostly becase Blink can do little on its own, most of the functionality is provided by [Chromium platform](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/displaying-a-web-page-in-chrome) - this includes network I/O, fonts and images processing, rendering, user input handling and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the link to CEF. From the docs, i was under the impression i could just use Blink as a library in my application.

Comment: As recommended by [the documentation](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/GeneralUsage#markdown-header-sample-application) I'd start from [cefclient](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/src/5b12134a4585f4d2f9e40c8d29292b4eb99c5ad8/tests/cefclient/?at=master) app.